# Edit shapefile using modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, editing

I have got the following problem:
I need to change some of the values of one attribute in my point shapefile. I want to do it in modelbuilder, but I don't know how. I have found a script which can do it in Python. The script is as following:

```
import arcpy
... 
... features = arcpy.UpdateCursor(r"C:\Users\peter.valent\Documents\ArcGIS\Data\Vah po LM\test_points.shp")
... for feature in features:
...         feature.precipitation = value
...         features.updateRow(feature)
... del feature,features
```

This is what I put to modelbuilder

Expression:

```
 myfcn(r"%file_name%","%value%")
```

Code Block:

```
import arcpy

def myfcn(path,value):
features = arcpy.UpdateCursor(path)
for feature in features:
        feature.precipitation = value
        features.updateRow(feature)
del feature,features
```

Comment: No sure to understand your problem. From what you stated, you only need in model builder a "Calculate field" and no python code. With "Calculate field", you can change the value of an attribute to some fixed value, to the value of another field and more complicated calculation! If you want do do more, you will have to explain it better so we can help.

Comment: You'll have to give us more information about what value you want to set. The Python code that you have found, is used when you don't want to use model builder; Given that you want to use Calculate Field in Model Builder, you don't need the python code. You just need to pass the proper value (or expression) to the Calculate Filed tool.